# Android ListView is not scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-tabhost

I have one **ListView** in  the tabhost. Everything works fine but the **ListView** doesn't scroll properly.

Here's my XML Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/liner"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/listView11"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>



        </FrameLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</FrameLayout>



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

Here's the JAVA class:

```
    public  class NotFragment extends Fragment {
    MyCustomAdapter myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    ListView listView;
    public static final String SecimId = "planet_number";

    public NotFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yemeklistesi, container, false);
        int secim = getArguments().getInt(SecimId);
        String Title = Gunler[secim];
     // get the listview
        TabHost mytabhost =(TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mytabhost.setup();
        //listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listInclude);
        TabSpec spec;
        spec = mytabhost.newTabSpec("yemekhane");
        spec.setContent(R.id.liner);
        spec.setIndicator("Yemekhane");
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView11);
        prepareData("Yemekhane");
        mytabhost.addTab(spec);
        mytabhost.addTab(mytabhost.newTabSpec("sosyaltesisler").setIndicator("Sosyal Tesisler").setContent(R.id.liner));
        mytabhost.addTab(mytabhost.newTabSpec("turuncusalon").setIndicator("Turuncu Salon").setContent(R.id.liner));

        // Listview Group click listener
        mytabhost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(tabId=="sosyaltesisler"){
                    prepareData("Sosyal Tesisler");
                }else if(tabId=="yemekhane"){
                    prepareData("Yemekhane");
                }else if(tabId=="turuncusalon"){
                    prepareData("Turuncu Salon");
                }
            }
        });
        getActivity().setTitle(Title);
        return rootView;
    }
    private void prepareData(String Birim) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int gunId = getArguments().getInt(SecimId);
        List<String> liste = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i<yemek.length;i++){
            if(yemek[i].getBirim().compareTo(Birim)==0 && yemek[i].getGun().compareTo(Gunler[gunId]) ==0 ){
                liste.add(yemek[i].getAd()+"-"+yemek[i].getOgunAdi());
            }
    }
        Menu = new String[liste.size()];
        liste.toArray(Menu);
        myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
        for(int i=0;i<Menu.length;i++){
            if(myAdapter.checkSeparator(Menu[i].split("-")[1])){
                myAdapter.addSeparatorItem(Menu[i].split("-")[1]);
            }
            myAdapter.addItem(Menu[i].split("-")[0]);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

   }
}`
```

And my CustomAdapter:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }
    public boolean checkSeparator(String Separator){
        for(int i=0;i<getCount();i++){
            int type = getItemViewType(i);
            if(type ==TYPE_SEPARATOR && getItem(i).compareTo(Separator)==0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;            
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }`enter code here`

}
```

`
Can someone please give me an advice?

Comment: give height fill parent it will work

Comment: there are two listview in your xml which is not scrolling?

Comment: listview11 isnot scrolling @Eddie

Comment: i tried but dint work. Can someone please give me an advice

Comment: is your listview showing items properly?

Comment: yeah items are showing but not all of

Comment: remove your linear layout because listview already scrolls vertically..

Comment: which linerlayout? android:id="@+id/liner"?

Comment: yeah remove that linear

Comment: sorry bro, doesnt work

Comment: I think I need to change.